# Making a dark theme plot in R

Tags: r

Let say I want to draw this function f(x) = x^2. I want the graph of the function to be any color I want and everything else (except the axis) black. Is this possbile?

Comment: The short answer is yes. Please add more details and show the code you've tried but doesn't appear to work.

Comment: i am new to R and programmering so i do not even know how to code this.

Answer (score 1):

```
graphics.off()
par(bg = "black")
curve(x^2, -2, 2, col = "green", axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
title("my plot", xlab = "X", ylab = "X^2", col.lab = "white", col.main = "white")
box(col = "white")
axis(1, seq(-2, 2, 1), seq(-2, 2, 1), col = "white", col.axis = "white")
axis(2, seq(0, 4, 1), seq(0, 4, 1), col = "white", col.axis = "white")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can `?plot` to see how to make it. Below is just an example

```
plot(x<-seq(-5,5,0.1),
     x**2,
     main="square function",
     ylab="f(x)=x^2",
     type="l",
     col=28)
```

[image]